# BrowserComponent fails to show in a Codename One desktop build

Tags: java, codenameone

My [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) app features an embedded browser component using the following code:

```
Form notesForm = new Form(subjectName);
this.currentSubject = subjectName;
notesForm.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
wb.setURL("jar:///alevelhtmlnotes/" + subjectName.toLowerCase()          +   ".html");notesForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);
 notesForm.show();
 startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 NotesProgressChecker time = new NotesProgressChecker();
 time.recordTimesAccessedValues(subjectName);
 notesForm.setBackCommand(com);
```

This works well in the simulator and device builds but when I build a native Windows Desktop app the browser component disappears.

Comment: Can describe in details what you mean under Failing? Some errors ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the packaging process that packages a broken VM for some reason: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1606

Its assigned to me so I guess I'm the one to blame for it not working. I'll try to get it working soon.

Comment: Isn't there any other way round about it,Is it possible to implement it Naively at this point while you fix the bug.

Comment: It is implemented natively. Send a build with include sources and package it locally with NetBeans as a workaround.